# $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{x^x-a^x}{x^a-a^a}\right)$ using L'Hospital's rule.

Tags: limits, analysis, derivatives, exponential-function

I have come across this question in one of my previous year question paper l tried solving it but I getting stuck in differentiating someone please help me out...

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word. One _solves_ equations; one _solves_ problems; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Answer (score 2):

For $a>0$ use
$$\frac{x^x-a^a}{x^a-a^a}=\frac{\frac{x^x-a^a}{x-a}-\frac{a^x-a^a}{x-a}}{\frac{x^a-a^a}{x-a}}$$ and a definition of a derivative.

By the L'Hospital we obtain the same result:
$$\frac{a^a(\ln{a}+1)-a^a\ln{a}}{a\cdot a^{a-1}}=1.$$